# How to make a variable input as is literal entry (ex: # 10 should not be a string)

Tags: python, input

Can any one help me with the below:

I am trying to pass the literal input, example if I enter 10 the function should be passed with int, but in below case its still passing string.

Can anyone please edit this for the code to pass as is entered type?

```
def str_len(s):
    if type(s) == int:
        return "You entered Integer, Please enter strings only to get length"
    elif type(s) == float:
        return "You entered float, Please enter strings only to get length"
    else:
        return len(s)

string = input("Enter a string to find its length: ")
print(str_len(string))
```

Comment: Don't use `string` as a variable name. Also what if they want to enter `'10'` as a string?

Comment: Hi Chris, I am just intending this program for literal entry of the type.

I changed the variable name to str, 

Thanks.

Comment: Oh no, `str` is a much worse name than `string`, it overrides a builtin type.  Use something like `s` if you want a simple name.

Comment: The correct way to test the type of a value is using `isinstance(s, int)`, not `type(s) == int`. You should also be using `raw_input` instead of `input` in Python 2, then attempting to convert `s` explicitly: `int(s)`, `float(s)`, etc, catching `ValueError` as necessary.

Comment: Thanks guys, will try your suggestions, Just started learning python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that

Whenever you take in an input, it will be a string, so `type(s)` will not give you your desired result.

However, you can get around this by using a `try/except` block to attempt to cast to a particular type, and if no error is raised, you know a valid type for what the string contains.

```
def try_as_type(t, v):
  try:
    t(v)
    return True
  except:
    return False

def check(s):
  if try_as_type(int, s):
    return "You entered an integer"
  elif try_as_type(float, s):
    return "You entered a float"
  else:
    return len(s)
```

Sample runs:

```
>>> Please enter a value:  10
You entered an integer

>>> Please enter a value:  1.43
You entered a float

>>> Please enter a value:  hello there
11
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, the above code worked. smart way to determine the type of passing valuee. Although I still didn't get to try and except in my training, i understood the code.

Comment: Glad to help, happy programming!